# Calling a PHP function that contains a javascript variable

Tags: php, javascript, function, variables

Users of my website will be able to input two numbers. One for the number of columns in a table and the other for the number of rows in the table. My javascript then constructs the code to create this table. By this I mean the opening tags for the table and the first row are added to a variable. It then adds the opening cell tag for the first cell in the row.

Now I call my PHP function within the javascript code like this :

```
<?php getCellInfo(1) ?>
```

This function takes the 1, queries a mysql database for the record with the primary key of 1. the function then echos a stored name associated with primary key 1.

I then add the tag to close this cell to the variabe holding the table code. I repeat this for the number the user entered for the number of columns, this is done with a while loop. When the loop finishes I add the code to end the row and start the next one etc till I close the table code.

I then change the html of a div to show the table. This works but obviously only fills all the cells with the same information. I want to increment the number I pass to the PHP function, which I can do in the javascript to increment the number when you move along cell but I don't know how to do this.

I tried defining a javascript variable and passing it into the PHP function. The variable was called cellNo and I tried this:

```
<?php getCellInfo(cellNo) ?>
```

But this didn't work can anyone help please.

Comment: PHP runs server side and javascript runs clientside, meaning all in-line PHP will run before your javascript runs.  To do what you're requesting, you'll most likely want to use AJAX calls to update the DOM dynamically.

Comment: Your entire application collapses if javascript is disabled.  Why not do those calculations on the back end?

Comment: show us your code so we can help!!

Comment: PHP runs on the *server* and JavaScript on the *client*.  You can't mix them together.  PHP generates the page, and gives it to the browser, at which point the JavaScript runs.

Comment: Please post some example code, and examples of what you have tried. If in doubt look at [this page on how to create good questions](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs on the server (before the page is loaded on the client side)

JS runs on the client side, and not on the server (obviously there are server side JS libraries like [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), but that is off topic)

Since they run at different times, it is not possible to pass a JS variable to a PHP function (since the JS variable was not instantiated yet).

In other words: when you call a PHP function:

```
myCustomFunction(jsVariable);
```

`jsVariable` is not defined yet.

**So what do I do?**

You can send your JS variable via AJAX to a PHP page in the background (i.e. when user clicks a button etc.)

**Where can I learn about AJAX and PHP?**

Here is a beginner tutorial on this subject:

http://www.handyphp.com/index.php/PHP-Resources/Handy-PHP-Tutorials/what-is-ajax-a-beginners-ajax-tutorial.html

Comment: thanks pzirkind that actually explained it, even in a way I can understand.  thanks again

Answer (score -1):

`fetchdata` is a php function declared beforehand in the that php files

```
$('#mytable').append(" < ? p h p echo fetchdata(2);  ?>");
```